# A badge should be created to warn users that they are spending too much time on SO

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

This is actually a sarcastic suggestion from my wife. I had described for her the fact that I had another 200+ day and that I was 110/150th of the way toward a "Legendary" badge. She wonders if there should be a "Get a Life"-badge.

Comment: Badges are intended to indicate you are doing something helpful for the site.  Your life?  How is that important in that context?  :-)

Comment: Exactly. How is my life important?

Comment: I feel the appropriate response to a remark for this would be, "My life for Stack Overflow!"  Do it in a warbly, space-y kind of voice.  If you want to practice, you can use [this helpful video](https://youtu.be/nWRlD0IiFwQ) as a reference.  If you find that clunky, you could also say, "For the Stack!"  Again, [here is another helpful reference](https://youtu.be/PYsJZqa62M4?t=9m52s) to get the voicing *just* right.

Comment: At 344 days consecutive, I'm starting to wonder about similar badges...

Comment: When I got the Fanatic badge, I started wondering the same thing. Is Fanatic really a good thing? What about a 10x fanatic?

Comment: And the Oscar of *SO regular* badge goes to... Jon Skeeeet.

Comment: The Fanatic badge is basically what you are asking for.

Comment: You've been Fanatic [since 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic?userid=1855677). If only this was a badge one could earn multiple times.

Comment: I guess the Fanatic badge is not enough ... the legendary also is not enough ... we need to create a "legendary Fanatic" badge and make it not gold but Diamond ... and like youtube : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube_Play_Button we should send them to user !

Comment: "srsly fanatic";

Comment: @DavyM What about 32x fanatic? (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309)

Comment: I'd argue that the Fanatic badge was a great boost to me. Once I got it, I was reminded of other (less useful) sites I had stopped visiting because I was spending more time on StackOverflow. Or of other sites (say, silly gaming) you'd feel guilty visiting 100 days in a row.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There's a similar badge: [Fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic).

You can see that more than 27520 users have already sacrificed their life for Stack Overflow. Show this to your wife, and tell her that we are doing this for a better life for the next generation.

[image]

Comment: Upvote for manual centering of that image. That's a lot of non-breaking spaces :-)

Comment: @Justastudent The more manual spaces you put, the less life you have.

Comment: Being guilty of using those spaces a lot ... dammit.

Comment: Fanatic badge isn't based on spending times on SO but rather days you have pinged it. So not a good answer.

Comment: @revo But it's still an indication on someone's life.

Comment: Yet this could have shown too little impact than OP's suggested one on someone's life.

Comment: My wife just had our baby last Thursday, so I'll see if she actually cares about my fanatic badge making the world better for his generation. ;D

Comment: My son in his thirties is an occasional user of SO and other SE sites although an infrequent answerer. So maybe my somewhat compulsive contributive behavior has a karmic balance with his consumptive behavior. It is interesting to speculate on how your offspring might interact with whatever SO-SE morphs into in the peri-singularity era.